# Combine Texture Paint With Normal Map From MultiRes Bake

Tags: texturing, normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have a Texture Painted Model that still has a MultiRes modifier active, and a normal map I baked from the multires. I'm trying to find a way to keep my texture painting and also incorporate my normal map.

So far my attempts have resulted in having one texture or the other (when "Use Nodes" is not selected in the material node window); see below:

[image]
[image]

When "Use Nodes" is selected with just about any combination of input and output connections I can think of, I just get a non-shaded figure like so:

[image]

What I want my model to look like is shown below:

[image]

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you simply need to make sure you apply a few options under the texture tab for the normal map image. With your normal map highlighted under "Texture," in "Image Sampling" make sure you check "Normal Map" and select "Tangent." Under "Influence" make sure "Color" is deselected and "Normal" is checked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I back up Tyler on his advice.

Your node materials don't seem to be right for Node so I'd say ignore Node for the moment. One thing I learned just now while fiddling with texturing is to NEVER mix Node and non-Node materials and textures or Cycles and Blender render engine materials. It will give totally unpredictable results.

Anyway just in case you really have to use node for more complex effects, here is the pure Blender Renderer Node version of simple texture UV mapping with Normal maps. I advise not to build it on top of the material you have already created but rather start from scratch:

[image]

PS: sorry not really an answer but I can't post comments yet...